# Extend "Tools" window in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, vsix

I'm looking how to inject my own page into VS2010 Tools->Options window in my open source project. ReSharper, VisualSVN and others are able to add their own page there and it seems like a natural place for settings. Unfortunately I'm not able to find any information or examples and I'm not perfectly familiar with the extension framework (been able so far to add my own tool windows, toolbars, menus etc.)

Any help would be appreciated.

Update: I've just got NuGet source code because they inject tool window too, trying to figure out how.

Comment: Try looking at msdn.microsoft.com. Here is an example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb968855

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [the Visual Studio Extensibility samples on MSDN Code Gallery](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vsx). Specifically, you'd be most interested in these:

1. [VSSDK IDE Sample: Options Page](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/VSSDK-IDE-Sample-Options-f152f574)
2. [VSSDK IDE Sample: WPF Tool Window](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/VSSDK-IDE-Sample-Tool-WPF-8823e6d1)

You can find general information on getting started with the Visual Studio SDK here: http://msdn.com/vsx